# read a txt file to matrix and cellarray Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a `txt` file with those entries and I would like to know how to get the numerical values from the second column until the last column in a matrix and the first column in a cell array.

I've tried with import data and `fscanf` and I dont understand what's going on.

```
CP6  7,2    -2,7     6,6 

P5  -5,8    -5,9     5,8

P6   5,8    -5,9     5,8

AF7 -5,0     7,2     3,6

AF8  5,0     7,2     3,6

FT7 -7,6     2,8     3,6
```

Comment: provide your code of what you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function should do the trick. It reads your file and scans it according to your pattern. Then, put the first column in a cell array and the others in a matrix.

```
function [ C1,A ] = scan_your_txt_file( filename )
  fid = fopen(filename,'rt');

  C = textscan(fid, '%s %d,%d %d,%d %d,%d');
  fclose(fid);

  C1 = C{1};
  A = cell2mat(C(2:size(C,2)));
end
```

Comment: Etienne. Your code is simmilar as Duck sent me. Thanks a lot 4 your help too. It was understandable.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you what you want based on the text sample you supplied.

```
fileID = fopen('x.txt'); %open file x.txt
m=textscan(fileID,'%s %d ,%d %d ,%d %d ,%d');
fclose(fileID); %close file
col1 = m{1,1}; %get first column into cell array col1 
colRest = cell2mat(m(1,2:6)); %convert rest of columns into matrix colRest
```

Lookup [textscan](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) for more info on reading specially formatted data

Comment: Duck. It was worthwile. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried xlsread?  It makes a numeric array and two non-numeric arrays.

```
[N,T,R]=xlsread('yourfilename.txt')
```

but your data is not comma delimited.  It also looks like you are using a comma to represent a decimal point.  Does this array have 7 columns or 4?  Because I'm in the US, I'm going to assume you have paired coordinates and the comma is one kind of delimiter while the space is a second one.

So here is something klugy, but it works.  It is a gross ugly hack, but it works.

```
%housekeeping
clc

%get name of raw file
d=dir('*22202740*.txt')

%translate from comma-as-decimal to period-as-decimal
fid = fopen(d(1).name,'r')  %source
fid2= fopen('myout.txt','w+')  %sink

while 1
    tline = fgetl(fid);  %read
    if ~ischar(tline), break, end  %end loop
    fprintf(fid2,'%s\r\n',strrep(tline,',','.')) %write updated line to output
end

fclose(fid)
fclose(fid2)

%open, gulp, parse/store, close
fid3 = fopen('myout.txt','r');
C=textscan(fid3,'%s %f %f %f ');
fclose(fid3);

%measure waist size and height
[n,m]=size(C);
n=length(C{1});

%put in slightly more friendly form
temp=zeros(n,m);

for i=2:m
    t0=C{i};
    temp(:,i)=t0;
end

%write to excel
xlswrite('myout_22202740.xlsx',temp(:,2:end),['b1:' char(96+m) num2str(n)]);
xlswrite('myout_22202740.xlsx',C{1},['a1:a' num2str(n)])

%read from excel
[N,T,R]=xlsread('myout_22202740.xlsx')
```

If you want those commas to be decimal points, then that is a different question.

Comment: EngrStudent. Thanks a lot 4 ur help. Unfortunately I does not work. xlsread seems to work just with excel not with txt.

Comment: Yes Engr. It is the case in which commas are used here for decimal points, not for separator. So here there are 4 columns and 6 rows. Obviously this is a piece of the huge txt file. The original one have many rows. Ill try to implement your code into my file. Thanks a lot buddy.

Comment: And again - it is a big ugly kluge, but it should work.  Perhaps instead of only fixing the commas, this could convert to CSV and save some code in the middle.